# Intercept parameter, $\beta_0$

Tags: r, regression, self-study, regression-coefficients, intercept

I have a hypothetical data given below that consists of 11 pairs of points (xi, yi ), to which the simple linear regression mean function $\mathbb E(y|x) = β_0 + β_1x$ is fit.:

```
 X     Y
 10    8.04
  8    6.95
 13    7.58
  9    8.81
 11    8.33
 14    9.96
  6    7.24
  4    4.26
 12    10.84
  7    4.82
  5    5.68
```

I have got intercept parameter,$\beta_0=3.001$

But the plot of the data is not showing the y-intercept is $3.001$. Rather the y-intercept is more than $3.001$. **WHY?**

[image]

I have used `R software` to calculate the parameters, $\beta_0$,$\beta_1$ and also to produce the plot.

```
 x1 <- c(10,8,13,9,11,14,6,4,12,7,5)
 y1 <- c(8.04,6.95,7.58,8.81,8.33,9.96,7.24,4.26,10.84,4.82,5.68)

 lm(y1~x1)

 plot(y1~x1)
 abline(lm(y1~x1))
```

**EDIT**

```
  ht <- c(169.6,166.8,157.1,181.1,158.4,165.6,166.7,156.5,168.1,165.3)
  wt <- c(71.2,58.2,56.0,64.5,53.0,52.4,56.8,49.2,55.6,77.8)

  lm(wt~ht)

  windows(9,6)
  par(mfrow=c(1,2))

  plot(wt~ht)
  abline(lm(wt~ht))

  plot(wt~ht,xlim=c(0,180),ylim=c(0,75))
  abline(lm(wt~ht))
```

[image]

How can i get the y-intercept? By expanding the straight line(population regression line) to negative axis of Y ?

Comment: why do you say so? we do not see the $\{x=0\}$ part of the graph.

Comment: Exactly, if you extend the line for $x1<4$, which is not shown in the graph, it will probably be $y1=3.001$ for $x1=0$.

Comment: I will migrate to Cross Validated as suggested. As you have already registered an account there, you can edit in the suitable tags yourself on the website.

Comment: This question seems to be predicated on a different understanding of "intercept": it is *not* where the graph meets the left hand of its box, but rather its value at $0$, *whether or not $0$ appears within the extent of the plot.*

Comment: In your plot, x=0 is not included.. try to use a larger x range.

Comment: This is essentially the same issue as [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51061/does-the-normal-probability-plot-systematically-underestimate-the-mean) - see the answer there. (That is, the problem is confusing the value of y at x=0 with the value of y at the left edge of the box.) Possibly close enough to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Hi, are you still looking for an answer? I hope mine helped. If it did, don't forget to vote it up. You can also check your favorite answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The intercept is in the right place. The problem is that `plot()` doesn't usually show the origin unless there are data points there. Note how the `plot(y1~x1)` starts at roughly $(4,4)$, not $(0,0)$. This isn't an error, just a result of us confusing plot borders with plane axes. Anyway, in order to force R to show the intercept where we'd expect it to be, you have to use the parameters `xlim` and `ylim` of the `plot` function. Try running this:

```
plot(y1 ~ x1, xlim = c(0, 14), ylim = c(0, 11))
abline(lm(y1 ~ x1))
```

And it give you what you want, i.e.:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

Try

> plot(y1~x1, xlim=c(0,14))

instead.

Comment: I get the true picture while using the command `plot(y1~x1,xlim=c(0,14),ylim=c(0,14))`. But how does the y-intercept change for changing the origin $(x,y)$$=(0,0)$

Comment: How can i get the appropriate picture of y-intercept parameter ,$\beta_0$ , if the data are `ht <- c(169.6,166.8,157.1,181.1,158.4,165.6,166.7,156.5,168.1,165.3)
wt <- c(71.2,58.2,56.0,64.5,53.0,52.4,56.8,49.2,55.6,77.8)`
and `lm(wt~ht)` ? I have edited the graph of this data.

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain why this answers to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
x1 <- c(169.6,166.8,157.1,181.1,158.4,165.6,166.7,156.5,168.1,165.3) 
y1 <- c(71.2,58.2,56.0,64.5,53.0,52.4,56.8,49.2,55.6,77.8)

lm1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)$coef
plot(y1 ~ x1, xlim = c(0, max(x1)), ylim = c(min(0,lm1[1]), max(y1)))
abline(lm1)
```

Of course it's practically meaningless to look at the intercept in the first place (since y can't be negative), but if you want to get this point across...