# linear regression intercept does not match

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, intercept

I have done a linear regression in R, using glm function. The calculated intercept says 0.98, but when I plot it, it does not seem to hit the estimated intercept on Y axis. Its far below. Here are my data and function:

```
event = c(2.2, 6.4, 3.4, 10.2, 4.45, 2.65, 8.25, 4.65, 3, 6.5, 5.25, 
8.65, 7.25, 6.4, 7.75, 7.45)

c(230208, 813178, 316617, 1531919, 576869, 270148, 1090947, 562643, 
439885, 745741, 666454, 1078175, 924429, 784333, 1091289, 948062)

fit=glm(event~size)

Call:  glm(formula = chr.co.count.wt ~ size)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         size  
  9.783e-01    6.528e-06  

Degrees of Freedom: 15 Total (i.e. Null);  14 Residual
Null Deviance:      83.08 
Residual Deviance: 2.849    AIC: 23.8




plot(size,events,col="blue",pch=16,xlab="size",ylab="events",ylim=c(0,12),frame.plot=FALSE,xlim=c(0,2000000),axes = F)

axis(side = 1,at = c(0,0.5e6,1e6,1.5e6),labels =  c(0,0.5e6,1e6,1.5e6))
axis(side = 2,at = seq(from = 0,to = 12,by = 0.5),labels = seq(from = 0,to = 12,by = 0.5))
abline(fit.wt)
```

[image]

Why is this discrepancy ? Am i missing something here ? I have also checked the std. err which is 0.27, still higher than what is being observed on plot.

Thank you.

Comment: See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhilv.png). Also see [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51061/does-the-normal-probability-plot-systematically-underestimate-the-mean) closely related question.

Comment: Wow ! Thank you. And I thought I knew regression :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The y-axis is where the x (size) is 0, not where R draws a vertical line. Eye-balling your graph it seems that the line is approximately 1 when size is null, so there is no conflict between your graph and your regression output.